After hooks in playwright takes time to finish
Playwright version: 1.43.1
I am currently investigating why some of my e2e tests are very slow; if it needs to be rewritten or just need to increase the default timeout. I recognize some tests that need to be rewritten and some test cases, even simple ones, are taking a very long time to finish due to after hooks.
Here is a sample snippet of my trace file:
After hooks is very slow for unknown reason.
[After Hooks] (https://i.sstatic.net/nuSnGU4P.png)
Just in case, anyone is wondering how the before hooks looks:
Before Hooks
I also have a fixture, but there are no custom hooks in there. Here is a snippet of the fixture:
export const test = base.extend<APIRequestOptions & APIRequestFixture>({
apiBaseURL: ['', { option: true }],
apiKeyCloakURL: ['', { option: true }],

asUser: async ({ apiBaseURL, apiKeyCloakURL }, use) => {
    const buildQueries = async (username: SupportedUsernames) =>
        createQueries({ apiUrl: apiBaseURL, keycloakUrl: apiKeyCloakURL, username });
    await use(buildQueries);
},

page: async ({ baseURL, page }, use) => {
    await page.goto(`${baseURL}`, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

    // added this to mimic the waiting time before the actual page is loaded
    await Promise.all([
        page.getByText('Initialising...').waitFor({ state: 'visible' }),
        page.getByText('Initialising...').waitFor({ state: 'detached' }),
    ]);

    // Re-authenticate if necessary
    await use(page);
},
});

Do you have any ideas why it has a very long duration in the After Hooks?
I did try to investigate if there are any Promise objects or locators without await but I assure you, there are none.
I am expecting that after hooks should have a short duration and not within 1-2 or more minutes range.

I don't see any after hooks in your code. Can you share a [mcve]? Thanks!

I have the same issue, and no clue why After Hooks take so much time. I found some github discussion about same issue, and the conclusion was in switching off trace recording, what is also not a real solution. Pasting link to it here: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/24210
